# Problems installing Vue js

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am trying to install vue.js with no success, yet npm is up to date.
When I run `vue init webpack vueapp` I get this error:

```
No command 'vue' found, did you mean:Command 'vpe' from package 'texlive-latex-extra' (universe)
vue: command not found
```

I have already installed the cli using  `npm install vue-cli`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `npm install -g @vue/cli` and then `vue ui` to start client in your browser.

Comment: This is what I get after running the npm install -g @vue/cli  /home/skndungu/.npm-global/bin/vue -> /home/skndungu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

Comment: Can you run Vue --version?

Comment: after installing , then I run vue create vue-app I get this  No command 'vue' found, did you mean:
 Command 'vpe' from package 'texlive-latex-extra' (universe)
vue: command not found

Comment: Just ignore fsevents. It works for me. Use your browser to import or create project.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `npm install -g @vue/cli`. Restart your terminal to make sure it shows up.

Also, make sure you have node 8.9+

From the docs:

> Warning regarding Previous Versions
>
> The package name changed from vue-cli to @vue/cli. If you have the previous vue-cli (1.x or 2.x) package installed globally, you need to uninstall it first with npm uninstall vue-cli -g or yarn global remove vue-cli.

Node Version Requirement

> Vue CLI requires Node.js version 8.9 or above (8.11.0+ recommended). You can manage multiple versions of Node on the same machine with nvm or nvm-windows.

Comment: I have the latest node  skndungu@skndungu:~$ node --version
v8.11.4

Comment: could it be an issue with the node_modules??

Answer (score 1):

For me `sudo` helps to solve it.
Try to use this command in terminal:

`sudo yarn global add @vue/cli`

Then you can check the version and all will work correctly.

`vue --version`

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed view?
Can you check `vue --version`

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Comment: This is what am getting  No command 'vue' found, did you mean:
 Command 'vpe' from package 'texlive-latex-extra' (universe)
vue: command not found

Comment: I wonder what `view` is. Other than that, if `No command 'vue' found` is mentioned as the problem, it should be expected that `vue --version` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli` instead of `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sudo`.

The `vue-cli` documentation at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html states that:

> To install the new package, use one of the following commands. **You
>   need administrator privileges to execute these unless npm was
>   installed on your system through a Node.js version manager** (e.g. n or
>   nvm).
>
> ```
> npm install -g @vue/cli
> # OR
> yarn global add @vue/cli
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `npm install -g pnpm` for the missing packages.

Then you can run `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Now you can ckeck the `vue --version`

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true
```

It works for my situation.